# IDP initiated single logout using SAML LogoutRequest , keycloak acting as identity broker

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, saml, sentry, single-logout

I have my application(React for front end and backend in spring boot) acting as External Identity provider while Keycloak is acting as Identity Broker. Sentry is a service provider in which I wanted to do Single Sign On. Now, I am successfully able to do both, a SP initiated SSO and IDP initiated SSO into Sentry.

I am looking for doing logout now.In case of Sentry, it doesn't support SP initiated Logout. Hence,I am only trying to achieve IDP initiated Single Logout.
Can someone help me here on, how this can be achieved, what should be the exact flow in this case and when my application sends a LogoutRequest to Keycloak, how it will understand it and forward it to Sentry ? What configurations are required in Identity provider configurations in keycloak and client configurations of Sentry ?